# Vim arrow keys are working as Ctrl+arrows in xterm

Tags: keyboard, vim, xterm

I'm stuggling with vim arrow keys.

My arrow keys are working as Ctrl+arrows in Vim.
But, this is happening only when using xterm + vim. I mean, arrow keys are working exactly as normal arrows when using "gnorm-terminal + vim" and "xterm + gvim".
Only this problem is occuring when using vim in xterm.

Is there a solution on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by making "tmux.conf" as following:

setw -g xterm-keys off

set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

Comment: FYI that won't do anything with recent versions of tmux. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/5ee4d991b6a325848083017665ac3d3ace2d1fa1